# Unexpected result related to open question whether $\sum x^{n^3}$ can satisfy an ADE

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, generating-functions

In Stanley EC2, it is an open question whether $\sum b_nx^{n^3}$ can satisfy an ADE. Stanley remarks that if this is true then it leads to a "completely unexpected result about representing integers as sum of cubes."

**QUESTIONS.**

(a) What completely unexpected result is he referring to?

(b) Does it have to do with the constructive nature of being able to write an integer as a sum of cubes? By Waring-Hilbert, we know it can be done with 9 cubes, but perhaps not constructively.

Comment: Summoning @RichardStanley ...

Comment: $\vartheta_{11}(z, \tau) = i \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n e^{2i\pi z\left(n+1/2\right)}e^{i\pi \tau\left(n + 1/2\right)^2}$ [is related to the Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Relation_to_the_Weierstrass_elliptic_function) by $\wp_\tau(z) = -(\log \vartheta_{11}(z;\tau))'' + c$, satisfying the differential equation $(\wp_\tau'(z))^2 = 4(\wp_\tau(z))^3-g_{2,\tau}\wp_\tau(z)-g_{3,\tau}$. So I guess it is about finding the same kind of relation for $\sum_n b_n e^{i \pi z n^3}$

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov unfortunately (or maybe fortunately!) summoning like this does not work on MO -- the '@' sign triggers a message only to those already involved with the question.

Comment: (The reference is the solution to Ex. 6.63.c, BTW.) If $f(x) = \sum_{n} x^{n^3}$ would satisfy an algebraic differential equation, then (I think?) so would its powers $f^k$. In particular, the coefficients $a_{n} = [x^n] f^2(x) = \# \{ (a,b): a^3+b^3 = n \}$ would satisfy a certain recurrence relation. My take is that Stanley refers to the fact that there's no known recurrence relation satisfied by $\{ a_n\}$.

Comment: see also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201415/identities-for-power-series-like-sum-n-zn3

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: your summons is answered! The comment of Ofir is essentially what I had in mind. There is no nice theory concerning the  number $f_k(n)$ of representations of $n$ as a sum of $k$ cubes analogous to sums of squares. If $\sum b_nx^{n^3}$ satistified an ADE then we would get a recurrence involving these numbers, which would be a big surprise to number theorists.